# access WEB-INF/jsp from html

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a simple application to test the communication between html and jsp. My jsp is located in

```
WEB-INF/test.jsp
```

Here is the structure of my files:

```
ProjectA 
  src 
    irstServlet.java 
  Web-Content 
    test1.html 
    WEB-INF 
      test.jsp
```

Here is the code from servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp");
  request.setAttribute("userName", request.getParameter("userName"););
  dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

First I have deploy in tomcat start my `test1.html`: It take me to the servlet: `FirstServlet.java` and I can enter userName there.

But after i enter the values in and press enter I expect it to forward me to `test.jsp` which is not working. I get the error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Edited: 
In my html I am trying to use it like:

```
<form method="POST" name="XX" action="/HelloWorldServlet">
```

Still not working.

Please can someone help me?

Comment: If you have your JSPs located in WEB-INF they are not directly callable. You usually do this to hide the JSPs because you want to call a servlet instead (as a front controller) which will call the JSPs only internally.

Comment: yes I know that thats why i created this servlet to access the jsp. The html is calling servlet and sever is using annotations and the servlet in turn is calling jsp located in WEB-INF

Comment: Then don't target your form action to the JSP. Call a servlet instead.

Comment: I changed it in html to target the servlet now but still no change

Comment: Please can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not look like it would compile at all.

- Parameter `response` has no type - should be `HttpServletResponse`
- There is a semicolon (`;`) after `request.getParameter("userName")`

Also I'm not sure why you're getting `RequestDispatcher` from servlet context rather than from the request - then again I've never checked if it makes any difference.

Anyway, I would rewrite `doPost` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.setAttribute("userName", request.getParameter("userName"));
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

EDIT:

I'm assuimng you have either a correct servlet mapping in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or your servlet is annotated with `@WebServlet` annotation:

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorldServlet")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    //your code
}
```

. If neither of those is true, that's your problem right there.

Comment: I added information about correct servlet mapping - check if your is correct as well.